# Finding stable distribution of a Stochastic Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices

so im currently looking at Markov diagrams and stochastic matrices and have become quite stuck on some parts of this question below and was looking for some help.

[image]

Here is what I have done so far,

For (a) I have constructed a Markov diagram from given information that I have excluded from this question as its not entirely relevant as it just explains the rules of a game. And have proven that  the associate matrix does indeed replicate the same as shown.

For (b) I have used the fact that the matrix is stochastic and used the left eigenvector of $\large[ 1 1 1 1 1 1 \large]$ to show that indeed $\lambda = 1$.

For (c)I have used the same eigenvector as in the last part and created the equations:

$1/2E+1/3C=M$

$1/2M+1/3S=E$

$1/2M+1/3S+1/2W=C$

$1/2E+1/3C+1/2N=S$

$1/3C+1/2N=W$

$1/3S+1/2W=N$

and $M+E+C+S+W+N=1$

But im not entirely sure how to use these equations to find the stable distribution.

And for (d) Im not entirely sure what to do here at all as this course has never involved the use of computors and hence I dont know what software to use to prove or disprove this.

Any help would be greately appreciated!

Comment: For (c), solve for $Tv=v$, i.e., solve for your $M,E,C,S,W,N$. For (d), I imagine they want you to start of with a random probability vector $w$, then apply $T$ repeatedly to it and see if it approaches $v$. Or perhaps start with $w=e_i$ and show that it approaches $v$ for all $i=1,\ldots,6$.

Comment: A hint for part (d) is that the Markov chain with transition matrix $\ T\ $ is [periodic](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Markov_chain,_periodic) with period $2$. If the chain starts in any of states $1$,$4$, or $5$, then it can only be in those states at odd times, and it can only be in the states $2$, $3$ or $5$ at even times.  Can you see what this says about the convergence or otherwise of
$$
T^k\pmatrix{1\\0\\\vdots\\0}\ ,
$$
for instance.